# Pass string array through nested Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

My usecase consists 3 Scripts:

`Script A.ps1` ← start script
`Script B.ps1` ← script in the middle
`Script C.ps1` ← target script to execute

**Constraints:** process spaces in path `string[] array` variables

---

`Script A.ps1`:

```
#SCRIPT EXPRESSION (TO PASS AS ARGUMENT)
$scriptC = "Script C.ps1"
$major = 1
$minor = 2
[string[]]$output = "Output A.txt", "Output B.txt", "Output C.txt"

$scriptExpression = 'powershell -File \"{0}\" -Major {1} -Minor {2} -Output {3}' -f ($scriptC, $major, $minor, $output)
Write-Host $scriptExpression -ForegroundColor Green

#SCRIPT EXPRESSION (TO CALL)
$scriptB = "Script B.ps1"
$config = "Debug"
$flag = 1
[string[]]$array = "String with space A", "String with space B"

$params = @("-File", "$scriptB", "-Config", $config, "-Flag", "$flag", "-ScriptExpression", $scriptExpression, "-Array", $array)
Write-Host "& powershell $params" -ForegroundColor Green
& powershell $params
```

`Script B.ps1`:

```
Param([string]$Config, [int]$Flag, [string]$ScriptExpression, [string[]]$Array)

Write-Host "`n_______________________________________________________________________________________`n"
Write-Host "Script B:`nConfig = $Config ($($Config.GetType()))`nFlag = $Flag ($($Flag.GetType()))`nScriptExpression = $ScriptExpression ($($ScriptExpression.GetType()))`nArray = $Array (Type: $($Array.GetType()) Length: $($Array.Length) <- WRONG LENGTH (2))" -ForegroundColor Yellow

Write-Host "`nCall Script C!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Invoke-Expression $ScriptExpression
```

`Script C.ps1`:

```
Param([int]$Major, [int]$Minor, [string[]]$Output = @())

Write-Host "`n_______________________________________________________________________________________`n"
Write-Host "Script C:`nMajor = $Major ($($Major.GetType()))`nMinor = $Minor ($($Minor.GetType()))`nOutput = $Output (Type: $($Output.GetType()), Length: $($Output.Length)) <- WRONG EVERYTHING" -ForegroundColor Green
```

---

Output:

```
powershell -File \"Script C.ps1\" -Major 1 -Minor 2 -Output System.String[]
& powershell -File Script B.ps1 -Config Debug -Flag 1 -ScriptExpression powershell -File \"Script C.ps1\" -Major 1 -Minor 2 -Output System.String[] -Array System.String[]

_______________________________________________________________________________________

Script B:
Config = Debug (string)
Flag = 1 (int)
ScriptExpression = powershell -File "Script C.ps1" -Major 1 -Minor 2 -Output System.String[] (string)
Array = String with space A String with space B (Type: string[] Length: 1 ← WRONG LENGTH (2))

Call Script C!

_______________________________________________________________________________________

Script C:
Major = 1 (int)
Minor = 2 (int)
Output = System.String[] (Type: string[], Length: 1) ← WRONG EVERYTHING
```

How is it possible to pass these `string[] arrays` with spaces to another script?

Comment: You're launching your scripts as separate processes. PowerShell arrays cannot be passed across process boundaries. Also, [DO NOT use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). See my answer to your other question for how to do this correctly.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I read the article (_"DO NOT use"_) but I can't find any alternative to the approach in my answer. How could I solve this in a simpler way?

Comment: The alternative is to simply not define the invocation as a string.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers but how can I pass the invocation to another script? I try to store non-string invocation in `$call` like `$call = .\ScriptC.ps1 -Major 6 -Minor 2 -Output "Abc" #<- empty variable` but thats don't work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pass the invocation"? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. I get the feeling this might be an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score -1):

I could achieve to call a `Script C.ps1` from `Script A.ps1` over `Script B.ps1` with: (*Content of Script B and C is in question*)

```
$output = @("Output A.txt", "Output B.txt", "Output C.txt")
$array = @("String with space A", "String with space B")

#INVOKE EXPRESSION SCRIPT C
$varScript = $("'{0}\Script C.ps1'" -f ($PSScriptRoot))
$varMajor = 1
$varMinor = 2
$varOutput = "'" + $($output -join "','") + "'"
$expression = "& $varScript -Major $varMajor -Minor $varMinor -Output $varOutput"
$expression = """{0}""" -f ($expression) #WRAP IN DOUBLE QUOTES

#INVOKE EXPRESSION SCRIPT B
$varScript = $("'{0}\Script B.ps1'" -f ($PSScriptRoot))
$varConfig = "Debug"
$varFlag = 1
$varArray = "'" + $($array -join "','") + "'"

$call = "& $varScript -Config $varConfig -Flag $varFlag -ScriptExpression $expression -Array $varArray"
Invoke-Expression $call
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Script B:
> Config = Debug (string)
> Flag = 1 (int)
> ScriptExpression = & 'C:\ScriptTest\Script C.ps1' -Major 1 -Minor 2 -Output 'Output A.txt','Output B.txt','Output
> C.txt' (string)
> Array = String with space A String with space B (Type: string[] Length: 2)
>
> Call Script C!
>
> _______________________________________________________________________________________
>
> Script C:
> Major = 1 (int)
> Minor = 2 (int)
> Output = Output A.txt Output B.txt Output C.txt (Type: string[], Length: 3)
>   - Output A.txt
>   - Output B.txt
>   - Output C.txt
> ```